# Post message from DB2 to Mq web sphere

Tags: db2, ibm-mq

Is there an alternate way to post message to mq from DB2 triggers other than MQSEND, I need to send mq group ID along with the payload.

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  What version of MQ?

Comment: @Charles ran the query to find my DB2 version. select getvariable(‘System.version’) from Sys Ibm.sysdummy1 and it telling DSN11010